# How can we understand Harrell-Davis quantile estimator in laymen terms?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, anomaly-detection

I am trying to create a model for Anomaly Detection in SQL and I have used MAD and Double MAD but I getting lot of False Positives. Because of which I believe the next robust method I can go for could Harrell-Davis quantile estimator. Could somebody simplify it for me and how the calculation is done with an example on a sample data like below?

Data:

```
(4, 10, 15, 18, 19, 20, 501, 502, 503, 504, 3000)
```

Clearly 3000 is the Outlier..